# Pytest API testing: separate tests for CREATE/UPDATE/DELETE vs one test

Tags: python, pytest

I want to test the following endpoints:

- Create user
- Update user
- Delete user

Which approach is better?

1. One test function with several asserts

   ```
   def test_api():
     create_user_response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data_for_create)
     assert create_user_response == 201
     created_user_id = json.loads(create_user_response.text)['id']

     update_user_response = requests.put(url+"/"+created_user_id, headers=headers, data_for_update)
     assert create_user_response == 201

     delete_user_response = requests.delete(url+"/"+created_user_id, headers=headers)
     assert delete_user_response == 200
   ```
2. Separate functions (How to share user-id between tests and run tests in the strict order?)

   ```
    def test_create_user():

    def test_update_user():

    def test_delete_user():
   ```
3. Some other approarch

Answer (score 1):

(2) is the preferred . Since it separate all the test case, in which it should be test, and know if further change in case will cause any error, rather than in All in one single case and then when it come error, you need to goto debug to see which case have error(s).
For id you can use @pytest.fixture.